# Multiple Linear Regression with Python statsmodel

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, patsy

In R, it is possible to execute multiple linear regression like

```
temp = lm(log(volume_1[11:62])~log(price_1[11:62])+log(volume_1[10:61]))
```

In Python, it is possible to execute multiple linear regression with 
R style formula so I thought the code below should work just as well,

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rando = lambda x: np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=x)

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'volume_1': rando(62), 'price_1': rando(62)})

temp = smf.ols(formula='np.log(volume_1)[11:62] ~ np.log(price_1)[11:62] + np.log(volume_1)[10:61]', 
               data=df) 
# np.log(volume_1)[10:61] express the lagged volume
```

but I get the error

```
PatsyError: Number of rows mismatch between data argument and volume_1[11:62] (62 versus 51)
volume_1[11:62] ~ price_1[11:62] + volume_1[10:61]
```

I guess it is not possible to regress just part of the rows in columns, cuz the data = df has 62 rows, and the other variables have 51 rows.

Is there any convenient way to do regression like R?

df type is pandas Dataframe and the column names are volume_1, price_1

Comment: It appears that the error is coming from [Patsy](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R-comparison.html) which is used for the R like formula syntax in python.  If you were using the same subset of rows for each term it would be easy just to use the same slice of df, but that is not the case in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Using an example from a [github question](https://github.com/pydata/patsy/issues/105) in the patsy repository, this would be the way to get your lag column to work correctly.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rando = lambda x: np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=x)

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'volume_1': rando(62), 'price_1': rando(62)})

def lag(x, n):
    if n == 0:
        return x
    if isinstance(x,pd.Series):
        return x.shift(n)

    x = x.astype('float')
    x[n:] = x[0:-n]
    x[:n] = np.nan
    return x

temp = smf.ols(formula='np.log(volume_1) ~ np.log(price_1) + np.log(lag(volume_1,1))', 
               data=df[11:62])
```

Comment: Why not use .shift() method on dataframe?

Comment: `temp = smf.ols(formula='np.log(volume_1) ~ np.log(price_1) + np.log(volume_1.shift())', 
               data=df[11:62])` also works.  But in cases where `data` is not provided as a dataframe will cause issues.  Data can be any dict-like object with the variables in the formula.  So `{'volume_1': [values], 'price_1': [values]}` could be used as the data argument and would fail if only `.shift()` was used.

Comment: ... and the reason you are trying to catch orbitrary type is the behaviour of R code?

Comment: Yes... the R [lm function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/lm) allows for multiple different datatypes to passed to the `data` argument.  So using the lag function as above allows `smf.ols` to be used just like in R.